# Spring Data Solr Result Documents with unwanted fields

Tags: spring-data-solr

When I run my spring data solr project with debug logging on I am noticing a lot of messages from `org.apache.http.wire`.  This is normal, however, much of the data being transfered is in fields that I am not mapping with my result entity bean.  I know you can tell a solr query which fields to return, but is there any way to tell spring data solr the same thing so that I am not transferring fields that I do not need?

The reason this is desirable is because some of these fields have very large data chunks in them (e.g. full text of the document).  I generally do not care about these fields, but I am still paying to transfer them over the wire.  Performance is a major concern here.

Is there any way to annotate or otherwise configure my result bean so that these unwanted fields are not transfered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Spring Data Repositories for Solr using `@Query(fields={...}` allows to define the `fl` parameter for the resulting solr query. See this sample [ProductRepository](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-solr/blob/1.5.0.RELEASE/src/test/java/org/springframework/data/solr/repository/ProductRepository.java#L86) from the tests.

Setting `fl` manually on the query can be done via [`SimpleQuery.addProjectionOnField("...)`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/solr/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/solr/core/query/SimpleQuery.html#addProjectionOnField-org.springframework.data.solr.core.query.Field-).

Comment: This seems to work.  However, it is tedious to mark all my query methods with only the desired data.  It seems like it would be more efficient and less error prone if the field list could be pulled from my result entity bean somehow (the query return type).  Should I file a feature request?

Comment: interesting approach - sure please open an issue for it. thanks!

Comment: Filed: https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATASOLR-266  Thanks.  I'd love to see this implemented!